# Merging 2 arrays in local storage in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, local-storage

I am trying to append an array of objects(new) to the local storage which already has some array of objects(previous) built in. Specifically, I want to merge these 2 arrays (previous and new) in the local storage.
Have tried the below code :

```
 function appendToStorage(name, data)
 {
    var old = localStorage.getItem(name);
    if(old === null) 
      old = "";
    localStorage.setItem(name, old.concat(data));
 }

 appendToStorage('ObjAry', JSON.stringify(objectIdArray));
```

And this is the output that I am getting :

```
["IrGszUBa0F","l366vn6mPa","2qn7JUoRwg","s2fZa0mXnb","WIaXLwmXRa"]["ZKHtnHoHgH","rtbI1sDfPm","U1eVDi9bNM","tUGNCl6hNl","lkq6tswVsZ"]
```

All I want is that, the second array should append to the first array so the output becomes :

```
["IrGszUBa0F","l366vn6mPa","2qn7JUoRwg","s2fZa0mXnb","WIaXLwmXRa","ZKHtnHoHgH","rtbI1sDfPm","U1eVDi9bNM","tUGNCl6hNl","lkq6tswVsZ"]
```

Can anyone guide me on what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close, there are just three small mistakes:

1. You are stringifying the array before concatenating it (so you are attaching a string to an array).
2. The default value for `old` is a string, which should probably be an array?
3. In order to use the array from localstorage, you need to parse it again using `JSON.parse`.

The resulting code would then be:

```
 function appendToStorage(name, data)
 {
    var old = localStorage.getItem(name);
    if(old == null) {
      old = [];
    } else {
      old = JSON.parse(old);
    }
    localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(old.concat(data)));
 }

 appendToStorage('ObjAry', objectIdArray);
```

If your local storage entry could contain other values as well, you could add a `try ... catch` block to your code to make sure that `JSON.parse` doesn't blow up if it fails to parse the value:

```
 function appendToStorage(name, data)
 {
    var old = localStorage.getItem(name);
    try {
      old = JSON.parse(old);
    } catch(e) {
      old = [];
    }
    localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(old.concat(data)));
 }

 appendToStorage('ObjAry', objectIdArray);
```

Comment: Thanku nils...Worked like a charm... :)

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating the whole object returning from

```
JSON.stringify(objectIdArray)
```

Try

```
appendToStorage('ObjAry', objectIdArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

LocalStorage stores a string values by a string key. To store arrays/objects as string we serialize them into JSON. So you need to parse JSON after `getItem`, merge parsed value with new portion of data, convert merged object to JSON and pass it to `setItem`.

```
function appendToStorage(name, data) {
  var old = localStorage.getItem(name) || '[]';
  var oldObject = JSON.parse(old) || [];
  var merged = oldObject.concat(data);
  localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(merged));
}

appendToStorage('ObjAry', objectIdArray);
```